# Facebook custom login on Titanium mobile

Tags: facebook, authentication, authorization, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm getting familiar with Titanium mobile, and now I'm developing iOS app with it.

I want to create custom login button.
I followed some instructions on the web, but still its not working.
The code is below.

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
Titanium.Facebook.appid = "APP ID";
Titanium.Facebook.permissions = ['permissions here'];

var login = Ti.UI.createButton({
  backgroundImage:'facebooklogin.png',
  width:250,
  height40:
});

win.add(login);

login.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  Titanium.Facebook.authorize();
});

Titanium.Facebook.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('me', {}, 'GET', function(e) {
                if (e.success) {
                   var data= JSON.parse(e.result);
                    Ti.API.info("Name:"+data.name);
                    Ti.API.info("email:"+data.email);
                    Ti.API.info("facebook Id:"+data.id); 
                } else if (e.error) {
                    alert(e.error);
                } else {
                    alert('Unknown response.');
                }
            });
        }else{
            if(e.error){
                alert(e.error);
            }else{
                alert("Unkown error while trying to login to facebook.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Dose anybody show me solutions?

thanks.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: oh yea, i forgot to write about it.
click the button, then nothing happens. I expected the modal window which is about facebook login, comes up, but....

Answer (score 0):

If you are already Authorized the Ti.Facebook.authorize method wont do anything.  Try clearing your app data from the device, and start over.